# How to speed up a PC with two OS on two hard drives

Tags: windows-8, bios, boot

I have installed Windows 8, 64 bit on one drive and windows 8, 32 bit  on another hard drive. At the time of booting, the system pops up the choice giving me the option to choose from the two volumes.

**The problem is**: From the time the CPU switch is pressed "on" to the stage where the system displays screen to enter into the BIOS and then to the next stage of popping up option to choose the one of two volumes, it takes ages. This time is still more if I opt the other volume on restarting.

Is there anything I can do in BIOS or in MBR for reducing this booting time?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the option in your BIOS for quick booting is enabled. Also, make sure the chain of boot loading is configured correctly. It goes from MBR > bootsector on primary active partition, then goes from there. It's possible that you may have them redirecting back and forth to each other, or maybe one of them is slower and from an older OS. Additionally, you can configure the timeouts on the bootsector too.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Where to find MBR in windows 8 and how to proceed from there?

Comment: Did you ever have Linux, or some other custom bootloader installed on this hard drive? Despite what I said in my answer, I highly doubt that passing from the BIOS to the loading screen would take more than a fraction of a second. It's possible that your computer is just old and slow to perform POST. Your best bet is to ensure quickboot is on, as that will make the most difference. How slow is "ages" for you?