# Where to find MBR in windows 8 and how to proceed from there to change its record?

Tags: windows-8, mbr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to speed up a PC with two OS on two hard drives](https://superuser.com/questions/532000/how-to-speed-up-a-pc-with-two-os-on-two-hard-drives)

My PC takes a considerably long time to boot, sometimes almost 2 to 3 minutes. Do see my earlier [question here](https://superuser.com/questions/532000/how-to-speed-up-a-pc-with-two-os-on-two-hard-drives).  Where I can locate MBR so that I can check its record.

Comment: What do you "plan to check" once you have it?

Comment: Why do you think locating the MBR would help resolve your problem?

Comment: @Ramhound I am not aware how to proceed from the answer to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/532000/how-to-speed-up-a-pc-with-two-os-on-two-hard-drives) question.

Comment: When you say "My PC has become very slow" 99% of the people here will think you are talking about windows is up and running and is slow. I reccomend you edit your question to clarify that you are having slow ***boot times*** (you can also delete the reply to me to help shrink the comments)

Comment: @user426 - I can't advise you on incomplete advice from somebody else.